# MedianFilter for large kernels and 16 bit unsigned images

Tags: c++, opencv, median

Update: I have now used the new approach.

```
Mat MedianFilter(Mat img, ushort SizeY, ushort SizeX, ushort kernelSize){

// Alloc memory for images
Mat medianImg(SizeY, SizeX, CV_16U, Scalar(0)), padded; 
copyMakeBorder(img, padded, kernelSize/2, kernelSize/2, kernelSize/2, kernelSize/2, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(0));



for (unsigned y = 0; y < 50; y++){
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < 50; x++){




        // Set median at central pixel pos
        medianImg.at<ushort>(y, x) = getMedian(padded(Rect(x, y, kernelSize, kernelSize)));//sorter[n]; 
            //sorter.clear();
    }

return medianImg;
}
```

And the get Median function adapted to 16 bit from the opencv routine:

```
int getMedian(Mat& img){
int channels = 0;
Mat hist;
int hist_size = 65535;
float range[] = {0, 65535} ;
const float* ranges[] = {range};
calcHist(&img, 1, &channels, Mat(), hist, 1, &hist_size, ranges);
float *ptr = hist.ptr<float>();
int median = 0, sum = 0;
int thresh = (int)img.total() / 2;
while(sum < thresh && median < 65535) {
    sum += static_cast<int>(ptr[median]);
    median++;
}
return median;
}
```

The problem now is that, I'm not sure if the borders are correct.

Comment: `kernel` is not continuous, so you can't use `datastart` and `dataend` directly. Use `kernel.begin<T>()` and `kernel.end<T>()` instead. Also you can use `std::nth_element` instead of `stsd::sort`

Comment: thx for the tip, but I think that my median is wrong.

Comment: take a look at http://answers.opencv.org/question/9494

Comment: thanks for the hint, I implement it, but I have problems with by borders although I padded them with zeros.